# \endhead in tabulary: "Undefined control sequence. \end{tabulary}"

Tags: tables, errors, tabulary

I am using the packages `tabulary`, `booktabs` and `longtable`. However when using `\endhead` I get the stated error.

```
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{RRRR}
\toprule
$U$ [kV] & $\lambda$ [$10^{-11}\,$m] & $\theta$ [$^\circ$] & $d$ [$10^{-11}\,$m]\\\midule\midrule
\endhead
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{tabulary}
```

Comment: `tabulary` doesn't have an `\endhead` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misquote the error message in your title. It is not `\end{tabulary}` that is undefined.

The first two errors in your document are

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \midule 

l.11 \end{tabulary}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\LT@echunk ->\crcr \LT@save@row 
                                \cr \egroup \global \setbox \@ne \lastbox \u...
l.11 \end{tabulary}
```

So the first is a simple typo `\midule` is undefined and should be `\midrule`.

The second says that `\LT@save@row` is undefined, which is an internal `longtable` command which latex tried to execute as part of `\endhead` which is only defined for `longtable`.